# Multipage JTable: impossible to display less items than rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, paging

I realized a JTable with a custom `AbstractTableModel` for implementing paging.
I wanna show 5 item per page, but I've a problem: if I have N item to show (with N which is a multiple of 5) everything it's ok, but if I, for example, have 14 element to show, I get an exception. The problem is that the method for getting each cell value, goes out of bound. In particular the problem is in method

```java
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    int realRow = row + (pageOffset * pageSize);
    return data[realRow].getValueAt(col);
}
```

in fact, we have 5 row (from 0 to 4) and 14 element, but obviously when we try to obtain the last element, we do: `realRow = 4 + (2*5)` and clearly I have no element at row 14.
How can I solve this problem? How can I tell to my program to stop getting value once reached the 14th file? Is it possible?

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify:  In your code, what is pageOffset and pageSize?  Those aren't any kind of standard tableModel fields, so knowing what they are for will help us understand your issue.

Comment: pageOffset is the page number (pageOffset = 0 for items from 0 to 4, 1 for items from 5 to 9, 2 for items from 10 to 14)
pageSize is number of elements per page (in this case is equals to 5)

Answer (score 1):

Just pin the the value to its acceptable maximum:

```
realRow = Math.min(realRow, getRowCount());
```

Addendum: In the [example cited](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/PagingorpagableJTableTableModelforlargedataset.htm), implement `getValueAt()` as follows:

```
// Work only on the visible part of the table.
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    int realRow = row + (pageOffset * pageSize);
    if (realRow < data.length) {
        return data[realRow].getValueAt(col);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also consider [`BasicArrowButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicArrowButton.html).

Comment: But then she would get a value for a row that doesn't exist, and that isn't really an improvement over an exception.  It just masks the issue, which is an improperly developed model.

Comment: Update based on the example cited.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your model's getRowCount method is inline with what you want it to do.  The getRowCount method should return an acceptable number for your table, so that it doesn't call getValueAt for any rows that don't exist.  So, if you have no row 14, your row count shouldn't be that high.

Comment: my getRowCount is

`return Math.min(pageSize, data.length);`

Comment: So, the `data` field is the data for the entire table across multiple pages, or is `data` different for each page?

Comment: data field is the data for the entire table  across multiple pages

Comment: So, if there are two full pages (5 rows each) and 3 rows on the last page, then the total amount of data is 13 entries.  For that last page, is your model getting a row of 2, or 3?  If you get in a 2, then you math (page * offset) is correct, and will convert 2 to 12, however if you are getting a 3 (I assume you are manually calling getValueAt), then you have an off by one problem...

Answer (score 1):

I think that not [easy job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8181813/714968), I suggessting to look at [aephyr's code](http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2008/03/jtable-pagination-example-using.html), maybe more easies way is implementing this [code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/PagingorpagableJTableTableModelforlargedataset.htm), but for real effect you have to lock `JScrollBars`, swith to [NEVER](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#scrollbars)

Comment: I've already seen both link you post and in fact i use the second one of them. But it only work with a number of element which is perfectly divisible (with remains 0) for the number of element displayed in every page