# set scroll bar position in JTable/SWT Table

Tags: java, swing, swt, scrollbar

I would like to ask question that is not directly related to any technology but it’s a logic level question. Forgive me if I am wrong.

I am trying to solve this issue in Java side.

We have a list view (may be JTable or SWT Table).  We are displaying records from a table in to that list. The table may have millions of records. And the table size is keeps increasing. As the table size is huge and it keeps increasing we are keeping a cache of 3000 records and displaying the cache in the table. So at a single point only 3000 records will be there in the view. At this time, the scroll bar of the view (JTable or SWT Table) shall be set based on the cache only (in this case 3000 records).

And based on the user events like, PgUP, PgDwn, DownKey, UpKey, Mouse Scroll etc we are refreshing the cache so that the view will be refreshed.

But we need to give users an actual feel that the scroll position based on the records in the table. I think it is not possible as the scroll position is set by the OS based on the number records in the display. Can somebody can assist me with an alternate method. If I am not explained my question correctly, I will explain this in details. Please help.

Comment: Are you looking for this method [setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(java.awt.Dimension)) ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually a scrollbar is set at the top of the list, or at the bottom, depending on if the property "AutoScroll" is set to true or false.

I believe there IS a method where you can set the scrollbar at a specific point, but last time I tried using it, it was kinda clunky.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to make the scroll bar do two things at once, and that can be confusing. You could use a separate control to the do the paging. A row of buttons in a `JToolBar` looks nice, but a `JComboBox` will take up less room. There's some good answers about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8389350/261156).