# Netbeans JTable Pagination

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, pagination

I never knew that `JTable` does not have pagination. Because of that I am now stuck with using `JTable` and I need to implement pagination. I have found many examples of Java Swing pagination but they are not implemented in netbeans. How will I implement pagination in my project (relevant code below)?.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Joseph
 */
public class SupplierForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form SupplierForm
     */
    public SupplierForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        supplierCombo = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        dataTable = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));

        supplierCombo.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "USER", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
        supplierCombo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                supplierComboActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        dataTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "ID", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(dataTable);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(173, 173, 173)
                        .addComponent(supplierCombo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 141, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 660, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(supplierCombo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(34, 34, 34))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void supplierComboActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        String tableName = (String) supplierCombo.getModel().getSelectedItem();
         DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dataTable.getModel();
         int c = model.getRowCount();
         for (int i=c-1; i>=0; i--){
            model.removeRow(i);
            dataTable.revalidate();
            }
        String sql = "select * from "+ tableName+"  ";
        try {
            try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SupplierForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            Connection connect = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Merlin1.accdb");
            Statement statmnt = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet rslt = statmnt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rslt.next()){
                String id = rslt.getString("ID");
                String name = rslt.getString("USER_NAME");
                String surname = rslt.getString("PASSWORD");
                //String age = rslt.getString("Age");
                model.addRow(new Object[]{id,name,surname});
            }
        } catch(SQLException e){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No Supplier exists with this name");

            }
    // dataTable.revalidate();

    }                                             

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SupplierForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SupplierForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SupplierForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SupplierForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new SupplierForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTable dataTable;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox supplierCombo;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to provide pagination support to a JTable in Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481138/how-to-provide-pagination-support-to-a-jtable-in-swing)

Answer (score 1):

you can to create a paginations two ways

1. on `Database` side, in `SQL statement`
2. display reduced number of rows in the `JScrollPane` with removed vertical and horizontal `ScrollBar`, method `JScrollBar.setValue(int)` can moving `JTable` inside `JScrollPane`

Comment: a tutorial link to implement and understand both of them would really assist me in coding.

Comment: @Namelus: For more on item 2, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8389513/230513).

Answer (score 0):

```
int crt = 1;

private void PREVMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {    

    DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel)jTable.getModel();
    tm.setRowCount(0);       

        try{                        

            ctr --;
            int page_num = (ctr-1)*5;  
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database","root","");
            state = connect.createStatement();

                if(page_num <=0 ){
                    PREV.setSize(0,0);
                    next.setSize(89,15);
                    res = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `item` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 0,5");
                        while(res.next()){               
                            int item = res.getInt("id");
                            String item1 = res.getString("item1");
                            String item2 = res.getString("item2");
                            Object record [] = {item,item1,item2};
                            tm.addRow(record); 
                        } 
                        ctr = 1;
                }else{
                    next.setSize(89,15);
                    res = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `item` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT "+page_num+",5");
                        while(res.next()){               
                            int item = res.getInt("id");
                            String item1 = res.getString("item1");
                            String item2 = res.getString("item2");
                            Object record [] = {item,item1,item2};
                            tm.addRow(record); 
                        } 
                }

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
} 
private void nextMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  

    ctr++;
    int page_num = (ctr-1)*5;

    DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel)jTable.getModel();
    tm.setRowCount(0);    

    int id = 0;  
    try{
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/database","root","");
        state = connect.createStatement();
        res = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `item` ORDER BY `id` ASC");

            while(res.next()){
                id++;
            }          

    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }

    if(id%5 == 0){
        int ans = id - 5;
        int ans1 = id / 5;
        int last = (ans1 * 5) - 5;

            try{

                if(page_num == ans && page_num == 5){

                    next.setSize(0,0);
                    PREV.setSize(89,15);

                    res = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `item` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT "+ans+",5");
                    while(res.next()){               
                        int item = res.getInt("id");
                        String item1 = res.getString("item1");
                         String item2 = res.getString("item2");
                         Object record [] = {item,item1,item2};
                        tm.addRow(record); 
                    } 

                }else{

                    if(ctr >= ans1){

                        next.setSize(0,0);
                        PREV.setSize(89,15);
                        res = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `item` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT "+last+",5");
                        while(res.next()){               
                            int item = res.getInt("id");
                            String item1 = res.getString("item1");
                            String item2 = res.getString("item2");
                            Object record [] = {item,item1,item2};
                            tm.addRow(record); 
                        } 

                    }else{
                        PREV.setSize(89,15);
                        res = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `item` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT "+page_num+",5");
                            while(res.next()){               
                            int item = res.getInt("id");
                            String item1 = res.getString("item1");
                            String item2 = res.getString("item2");
                            Object record [] = {item,item1,item2};
                            tm.addRow(record); 
                        } 
                    }
                }

            }catch(SQLException e){
                System.out.print(e.getMessage());
            }

    }else{

        int ans = (id/5) + 1;
        int last = (ans * 5)-5;

        try{

            if(ctr == ans || ctr > ans){   

                next.setSize(0,0);    
                PREV.setSize(89,15);

                res = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `item` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT "+last+",5");
                    while(res.next()){
                        int item1 = res.getInt("id");
                        String size_Code = res.getString("size_code");
                        String size_Name = res.getString("size_name");
                        Object record [] = { item1, size_Code, size_Name};
                        tm.addRow(record);                    
                    }   

            }else{

                PREV.setSize(89,15);

                res = state.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `item` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT "+page_num+",5");
                    while(res.next()){               
                            int item = res.getInt("id");
                            String item1 = res.getString("item1");
                            String item2 = res.getString("item2");
                            Object record [] = {item,item1,item2};
                            tm.addRow(record); 
                        } 
            }

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }        
    }

    }
```